# HTML Template Language for PHP

Tags: php, html, templates

I'm making php content management system with simple template integration and I can't find any good template language. Currently I'm using xml templates and parsing them with php DOM. Here's how template looks like:

```
<div class="one_fourth">
    <h4 class="section-header"><span><CMS_STRING type="string" name="title" title="Title" /></span></h4>
    <p><CMS_STRING type="string" name="body" title="Body text" tooltip="" /></p>
    <p><CMS_STRING type="link" name="link" title="Link" /></p>
</div>
```

In php I parse all CMS_STRING tags with DOM getElementsByTagName and then I pull value from database for visitors or generate editable inputs for admin.

One problem with xml is that I can't use tags in attributes for example:

```
<a href="<CMS_STRING name="url" />"></a>
```

Another problem is with php DOM quote escaping. It looks ugly and unreadable. Let's say I want to put JSON in attribute for localized title:

```
<CMS_STRING type="string" name="title" title="{&quot;enUS&quot;:&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;enGB&quot;:&quot;Title&quot;}" />
```

So what other template language I could use here? I also need it to support xml (for example getting CMS_STRING inner html). All template languages that I found are premade with caching engines and all other things that I don't need. I just need a simple language with a parser, I'll handle other stuff by myself.

Thanks.

Comment: you might want to try mustache https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605/php-as-a-template-language-or-some-other-php-templating-script?

Comment: What I need is a bit different template language than most of them. Look at the smarty solution comments bellow.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PHP Templating Language](http://phptemplatinglanguage.com/). Your life will be better, happier, simpler, faster, the people around you will thank you for generations to come, puppies and kittens around the world will die less, and global warming will probably even slow down a little.

Comment: No PHP is not a templating language!! what about security? htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') on every single echo ? A function e() to escape ? PHP should be a templating language, but because of it's vulnerabilities it's not. Say you forgot to escape, well that's too bad, your website can be doomed.

Comment: @petter which is why you process content in your controller, before handing it over to the template, following the MVC model. It's a matter of organizing yourself; relying on template languages to do this for you is only good to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Name some of the ones you looked at and cannot use so we don't keep suggesting duplicates.  Have you looked at [Smarty](http://smarty.net)?  It is great and sounds like it can meet your needs.

Yes Smarty has caching, but you don't have to enable it.  The only resulting files you will get are compiled versions of your templates, but this is just for efficiency, and you can disable template caching (in exchange for performance).

Comment: Problem with smarty is that it takes php variable and puts it into template and I don't have any variables when loading template. What I do is find all cms strings and load plugin according to their type which processes it. I should have also noted that templates are nested and the same template could exist multiple times but with different data.

Comment: You don't have to have any variables in Smarty.  It can be plain HTML or HTML with placeholders.  You can also render the same template as many times as you want with different data.  I don't see any reason why it cannot do what you want.

Comment: I agree with @drew010.  I use smarty, and although I didn't love it at first, I absolutely love it now.

Comment: I guess we didn't understand each other. What I need is template parser not a template engine. Smarty would be good if I were only loading database data but what I do is generating dynamic admin cp according to template. For this I need to get all template variables (cms_string in my code) and I haven't found this feature in smarty.

Comment: Wow. Well I guess that's original.

Comment: Seriously though, you are not supposed to read data from a template and in turn that should not dictate your application logic, you are doing it the other way around. No wonder you didn't find a templating system to fit those needs.

Comment: Well, that's how I designed it. I wanted a cms that could be edited through templates only, without need of php. Only thing where php is needed is custom input types, like file upload but that will be handled in plugins.

Comment: I think, if you allow me the suggestion, that you have two things there you will want to split. An elegant solution for example could be having the configurable data/parameters in a separate json or xml file; and then your php logic can read the parameters from there and handle the templates in a conventional way. That way parameters can still be edited with no need for php and it's super easy to maintain the parameters file, the template, and the php logic.

Comment: Might work but this is a bit inconvenient as template vars and parameters file would have the same data just in another format. Thanks for suggestion anyway, I'll keep that in mind if nothing works out. Maybe I should use just a simple regex but I'm not sure about performance

Answer (score 1):

### Popular template engines :

- **[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)** (becoming outdated)
- **[Latte](https://github.com/nette/latte)** (used mostly by the **[Nette](http://nette.org/)** community)
- **[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)** (used mostly by the **[Symfony](http://symfony.com/)** community)
- **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)** (official implementations of this templating engine exist in more than two dozen proramming/scripting languages)

I tend to favor **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)**, mostly because it has **[an official JS version](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)**,  **[an official Ruby version](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache)**, **[an official Java version](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java)**, etc. It allows you to use the same templates frontend and backend, which is very useful for widgets that are first rendered in background and rerendered in foreground at updates.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of templating systems available [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Moustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/), and of course PHP itself.

One thing that I like about an actual templating system instead of using plain old PHP is if you aren't familar with the MVC design pattern, it pretty much forces you to do the VC portion of it, and teaches you the importance of it... I say pretty much because you can still do business logic in them, but they generally make it difficult, and discourage you.

I believe all of them having caching built in, so execution wise, should be just as fast as a regular php script.